# Set select field value in bootstrap form programatically with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-4

How can I select one of the options in the select field programatically (based in some variable)?

This is the code for the template:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="selectAction">Action</label>
    <select ngModel name="option" class="form-control" id="selectAction">
        <option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op.id">
            {{ op.description }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to get. Is it **op.desciption** or entire **op**

Comment: I want to display one of the posible options programatically. Display op.description in the select field.

Comment: so you want to store the click option right. Whatever you click

Comment: No, I want to display one of the options without interaction. Set this value programatically depending in some variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as follows,

```
  <select class="form-control" name="selectAction" 
 [(ngModel)]="selected">
        <option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op.id">>
          {{op.description}}
        </option> 
  </select>
```

and in component , you can set the selected value as

```
this.selected = this.options[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="selectAction">Action</label>
    <select ngModel name="option" class="form-control" id="selectAction" (change) = "functionname(t.value)" #t>
        <option *ngFor="let op of options" [value]="op.description">
            {{ op.description }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

> In .ts

```
functionname(value){
console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: according to your need change **[value] = "?"**